# Category of ordinal numbers

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Delta$ be the category of finite ordinal numbers with order-preserving maps, i.e., $\Delta$ consists of objects strings 
$$
[n]:  0 \to 1 \to 2 \to \dots \to n.
$$
A morphism $f:[n] \to [m]$ is an order-preserving function (a functor) and we can think of the morphisims like diagrams where arrows don't cross.

[image: Simplicial morphisms.]

**My questions are:**

1. Why can't the arrows cross?
2. What does it mean if an arrow crosses?

I hope I explained myself :) Thank you!

Comment: The way that morphisms in this category are defined means that if you draw a morphism as a diagram with rows 0, ..., n and 0, ..., m, with arrows from the top row to the bottom row, then these arrows won't cross.

Comment: So its by definition? What happens if they do cross?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306161/induced-map-on-simplices-from-order-preserving-maps-between-finite-ordinal-numbe

Answer (score 4):

A morphism in this category is an order preserving map. Look at a morphism $f$ from $[m]$ to $[n]$, and draw it in the following way:

1. In one line, write the numbers $1$ to $m$ in order.
2. In another line, write the numbers $1$ to $n$ in order.
3. Connect each $x$ in the first line to $f(x)$ in the second line, using a straight arrow.

The arrows don't intersect ("cross") since the morphism is order-preserving. Indeed, if two arrows $x \to f(x)$ and $y \to f(y)$ crossed, say $x < y$ and $f(x) > f(y)$, then $f$ wouldn't be order-preserving. The converse (if the arrows don't cross then $f$ is order-preserving) is true as well.

What happens in the arrows cross? Then the corresponding function doesn't appear as a morphism in our category, since this is how we defined our category.